# Andoid app (React Native) works perfectly fine running locally, but stuck on splash screen in production

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, expo

I've built my app using expo. If I run it locally (`npx expo start`) it works perfectly fine.
I've tried running a production build (`npx expo start --no-dev --minify`) and also, it works perfectly fine.

I'm working with Typescript on strict mode and made sure no errors are present in my code.

I've tried running the production app on my device while connected to my computer, and running `adb logcat | findstr MY.APPS.PACKAGE` and either I'm missing something there or there's really nothing useful to learn from he logs I get.
How can I figure out why it isn't going past the splash screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone facing a similar issue, I was able to solve my problem and get better logs by downloading the apk directly from the play store using a third-party website (https://apkcombo.com), and then using Appetize.io to run in and I got better logs.

specifically my issue was missing two dependencies for the react navigation (I was missing `react-native-screens` and `@react-native-community/masked-view`. Installing both solved my issue and the app works fine in production now.